# How to receive variables autocomplete from all opened tabs in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is that possible in Visual Studio Code to receive autocomplete suggestions from all opened files, instead of current file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All Autocomplete](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Atishay-Jain.All-Autocomplete).

Provides autocompletion in Visual Studio Code items based on all open editors.